# Gráfica de la tangente

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Yo tengo lo siguiente

**Codigo:**

```
 import math
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 fn = np.tan

 x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 1000)
 points = [i * np.pi/2 for i in range(-4, 5)]
 labels = ["-2π", "-3π/2", "-π", "-π/2", "0", "π/2", "π", "3π/2", "2π"]

 fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
 ax.plot(x, fn(x))
 ax.set_xticks(points)
 ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

 for pt in points:
     ax.plot(pt, fn(pt), "ok")

 ax.hlines(0, x[0], x[-1], "k")
 ax.vlines(0, -1, 1, "k")

 plt.show()
```

**Me gustaría tomar mi código existente, y (preferiblemente) usando matplotlib, trazar dos períodos de mi función trigonométrica dada, y alinear un par de puntos en el gráfico con un par de puntos en mi función. Para la función seno y coseno funciona.**

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Y que problema tienes al implementar lo que quieres?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SOes te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y obtengas tu primera medalla! También lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/482794/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema no es de matplotib o de Python, sino del propio concepto matemático de la función `tan()` y lo que intentas hacer.

La función `tan()` tiene varias asíntotas en pi/2, 3pi/2, 5pi/2, etc., puntos en los que es discontinua y tiende a infinito (si te acercas a esos puntos por tu izquierda) o a menos infinito (si te acercas por la derecha).

Esto causa dos problemas en tu gráfica:

- Ya que la gráfica tiene puntos en los que se va a infinito, aunque realmente debido a errores de redondeo el valor calculado no será infinito, sí que será muy grande. Al dejar que matplotlib ajuste automáticamente la escala del eje y, resulta que para poder hacer visibles esos números tan grandes debe usar un rango para la `y` también muy grande. Eso hace que la función se vea prácticamente como cero en todos los puntos salvo en los que se iría a infinito. Por tanto no se está viendo la parte interesante de la función, es decir, qué forma tiene esa función en los puntos entre las discontinuidades.
- Por otro lado quieres marcar ciertos puntos en la función, en ciertos lugares elegidos mediante la lista `points`. Por desgracia los puntos que has elegido son múltiplos de pi/2, por lo que entre ellos están precisamente esos puntos en los que la función tiene discontinuidades y para los que no toma un valor definido (y que por errores de redondeo se computarán como valores muy grandes, positivos o negativos)

Debido a estos problemas tu gráfica sale así:

[image: Mal]

Los puntos negros que salen fuera del eje x serían teóricamente valores indefinidos (infinito o menos infinito). Por errores de redondeo han sido calculados como números muy grandes (del orden de 1e16, o -1e16), que arruinan la escala de la gráfica como te he explicado.

Por otro lado la linea azul teóricamente debería tender a infinito o menos infinito al acercarse a esos puntos, pero ya que `linspace()` no es realmente un muestreo de resolución infinita (continuo), no llega a pasar exactamente por esos puntos, sino por otros próximos en los que la función no toma valores tan grandes como en la discontinuidad. Por eso la gráfica se ve como una línea azul plana.

### Soluciones

Para que la gráfica no se vea plana, no debes dejar que matplotlib ajuste automáticamente el rango de y, sino que puedes forzar tú uno. Por ejemplo, entre -5 y 5. Basta añadir una línea final (antes de `plt.show()`) que diga:

```
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
```

Y seguramente cambiar también la línea negra vertical para que vaya de -5 a 5 en vez de -1 a 1 (es decir `ax.vlines(0, -5, 5, "k")`).

Ahora tu gráfica se verá así:

[image: Bien]

Como ves ha mejorado mucho, y ya se puede ver la forma tipica de la función tangente. Hay un problema y es que ha sido dibujada como una función continua (cuando en realidad es discontinua). Las líneas azules verticales no deberían estar. De todas formas no queda mal, pues parece que estás dibujando las asíntotas, para referencia.

En cuanto a los puntos negros, los que caían en las discontinuidades se han salido de la escala y no son visibles. Los restantes se ven donde deberían. ¿Qué querrías hacer con los que no han salido? No tiene sentido tratar de pintarlos puesto que para esos puntos la función no está definida. Yo lo dejaría así, pero puedes plantearte si pintar quizás otros puntos, como pi/4, etc para los que sí está definida.

Comment: No me muestra la gráfica. He seguido tus sugerencia, no sé que salió mal.

Comment: Listo, ya lo arregle...